# AggregateRating Schema markup not showing rating stars under my app snippet google search result

Tags: web, schema, google-search, google-search-console

I'm working on web app providing self storage services and we have a landing page for each city we provide our services in.

So we need show the rating of our services when google shows our search results like the image below.

[Starred google search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaAZz.png)

Even we added `AggregateRating` schema and `SelfStorage` schema in a propriate way as validator.schema.org and search.google.com/test/rich-results not showing any errors we still don't have these stars in our search results.
So anyone know where I can start as all debugging tools shows no errors?

Our app is next.js app and we collecting the reviews in a page in out website.

I'm tried to show these stars so I did all the suggested schema fixes but the result was the same to show the search result without the stars.

Comment: Google does not show review stars for reviews on your website about your own business.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath No, Why you say this there is a lot of videos explaining how to show these stars for your local bossiness using `AggregateRating`

Comment: This part of the Google guidelines explains about LocalBusiness and self serving reviews: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/review-snippet#self-serving

Comment: @TonyMcCreath I think that part from guidelines talking about the same entity. But my case is different because the entity that manages the reviews is the organization and the entity that being reviewed is the localBusiness.

Comment: Is the local business part of the organization?

Comment: @TonyMcCreath yes

Comment: Which means the reviews are self-serving. The website is listing local businesses that are part of the organization that owns the website.